# How can I detect which cURL requests my AWS instance is handling?

Tags: python, curl, amazon-web-services, python-requests, ddos

We run AWS to receive about 10 different requests from the client app, some of which may add rows to a database or return a fail condition. Today, we suddenly started getting too many requests (Similar to a DDOS although I don't think it's malicious) and the server has stopped responding to some big requests.

Is it possible to detect which cURL requests the server is receiving from the client (e.g. mydomain.com/client/req1?1=1&2=2 vs mydomain.com/session/req2?3=3&4=4) so we can figure out where all the extra requests are coming from?

Thank you,

Comment: what server? (nginx, apache) which wsgi connector? which python framework is your app written in (tornado, flask, django)?

Comment: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Um, did you look at the http headers?